# Does solidity support varargs arguments?

Tags: go-ethereum, stack

I have to extend my `modifier` to support different number of input arguments. Modern languages as `Java` support `varargs` arguments, but I do not see any information about it in `solidity`.

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/how-many-arguments-can-solidity-take) is the ambiguous information regarding the stack for input parameters either not limited or limited up to 16 params.

Do you know more about this issue? Is it possible to define `varargs` as an input parameter for a `function` or `modifier`?

Comment: I think all the params are strung together as one string of bytes. There's probably a way to access it but you won't know how the arguments were supposed to be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity currently does not support defining `varargs` as an input parameter for a function or modifier. However, there is a way to add anonymous params (e.g. with no name).

Answer (score 1):

In Solidty, codes convert to EVM bytecode in two different ways: directly from solidity code to EVM opcode ("old codegen") or intermediate representation (“IR”) in Yul (“new codegen”), if you have more than 16 variables in one function in old codegen you get "stack is too deep" error, for solving this problem you can pass variables in less than 16 variables packages or using turning on "viaIR" . viaIR lets you use more than 16 variables.